# Java: Calculating time zone difference

Tags: java, timezone, dst

How do I get the time difference from GMT for a specific date and time zone in Java?

Determining whether a specific time zone is in DST is quite straight-forward:

```
boolean isIsraelInDST = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Israel").inDaylightTime(new Date());
```

How do I get the actual time difference?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `TimeZone`,  [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use TimeZone.getRawOffset(): *Returns the amount of time in milliseconds to add to UTC to get standard time in this time zone. Because this value is not affected by daylight saving time, it is called raw offset*.

If you want the offset including DST then you use TimeZone.getOffset(long date). You should provide the concrete date to the method, eg now - System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: I want the offset *including* DST.

Comment: Sorry to post to such an old thread but I have a confusion.
If I use the TimeZone.getOffset(long date) does it assume the date parameter is in local time or UTC?  Specifically if you call it with a date that is a few hours before a day light saving time switch in new york but a few hours after in UTC will it include the switch or not?

Comment: long date is milliseconds from 1970-01-01 UTC.

Comment: Update: The `TimeZone` class was supplanted years ago with the adoption of JSR 310. Instead, use `ZoneId` and `ZoneRules`.

Answer (score 17):

## tl;dr

```
ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )   // Specify a time zone.
    .getRules()                   // Get the object representing the rules for all the past, present, and future changes in offset used by the people in the region of that zone.
    .getOffset( Instant.now() )   // Get a `ZoneOffset` object representing the number of hours, minutes, and seconds displaced from UTC. Here we ask for the offset in effect right now.
    .toString()                   // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> +13:00

For the first moment of a certain date.

```
ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )
    .getRules()
    .getOffset( 
        LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.AUGUST , 23 )          // Specify a certain date. Has no concept of time zone or offset.
        .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Determine the first moment of the day on that date in that region. Not always `00:00:00` because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time.
        .toInstant()                                      // Adjust to UTC by extracting an `Instant`. 
    ) 
    .toString()
```

> +12:00

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The other Answers are outmoded, as the `TimeZone` class is now legacy. This and other troublesome old date-time classes are supplanted by the *java.time* time classes.

## java.time

Now we use [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html), `ZoneOffset`, and `ZoneRules` instead of the legacy `TimeZone` class.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

Fetch the rules for that zone.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
```

Ask the rules if Daylight Saving Time (DST) is in effect at a certain moment. Specify the moment as an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
boolean isDst = rules.isDaylightSavings( instant ) ;
```

> How do I get the actual time difference?

Not sure what you mean, but I will guess you are asking for the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) in effect at that moment for than zone. An offset is a number of hours, minutes, and seconds displacement from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). We represent an offset using [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes in offset used by the people of a particular region. We represent a time zone using [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) class.

Because the offset may vary over time for a region, we must pass a moment when asking for an offset.

```
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( instant ) ;
```

Generate a String representing that offset in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format.

```
String output output = offset.toString() ;
```

You can ask for the offset as a total number of seconds.

```
int offsetInSeconds = offset.getTotalSeconds() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 14):

I suggest to add summer/winter time offset to getRawOffset:

```
    TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
    TimeZone tz2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    long timeDifference = tz1.getRawOffset() - tz2.getRawOffset() + tz1.getDSTSavings() - tz2.getDSTSavings();
```

Comment: Don't you need to check whether DST is in force before you adjust using tz2.inDaylightTime( new Date() );

Answer (score 8):

I see this is an old thread - but adding this since I had a similar requirement recently - 
This gives the actual difference in millis based on the CURRENT time(millis from epoch).

```
    TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York").getOffset(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public String timeZone(Date date) {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    long millis = timeZone.getRawOffset() + (timeZone.inDaylightTime(date) ? timeZone.getDSTSavings() : 0);

    return String.format("%s%s:%s",
            millis < 0 ? "-" : "+",
            String.format("%02d", Math.abs(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))),
            String.format("%02d", Math.abs(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))))
    );
}
```